# why my template is showing me error message Reverse for 'tag_quotation_list' with arguments '('fre mov co',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

**models.py:**

```
class Quotation(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      text = models.TextField()
      created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
      tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name='tag')


 class Tag(models.Model):
      tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**url.py:**

```
url(r'^profile/tags/$', tag_list, name='tag_list'),
url(r'^profile/tags/(?P<tag>\w+)/$', tag_quotation_list ,name='tag_quotation_list'),
url(r'^profile/tags/(?P<tag>\w+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',display_quotation,
     name='display_quotation'),
```

**views.py:**

```
def tag_list(request):
    tags = Tag.objects.values_list('tag_name',flat=True).distinct()
    return render(request,'add/taglist.html',{'tags':tags})

def tag_quotation_list(request,tag):
    quotation_list = Quotation.objects.filter( tags__tag_name=tag)
    return render(request,'add/tagquotationlist.html',{'quotation_list':quotation_list})
```

**taglist.html:**

```
<h1>Tags</h1>
{% for tag in tags %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'add:tag_quotation_list' tag %}">{{tag}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

in this html i am getting error in 3rd line.Error message is:

```
Reverse for 'tag_quotation_list' with arguments '('fre mov co',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['add/profile/tags/(?P<tag>\\w+)/$']
```

please help me where i am committing mistake

Comment: To downvoters: It's useless for the community to downvote without saying to the author why.

Answer (score 2):

If your tags can contain spaces, your urlpattern is wrong - `r"/\w/"` wont match `"/fra mov co/"` :

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"/(?P<tag>\w+)/", "/far mov co/") is None
True
```

Comment: bruno desthuilliers
i am using windows7 and python3.4.2 and django 1.7.1 how to solve this problem

Comment: Don't use spaces :P...if you need a separator use a "-"

Comment: @kanchan: the problem would be the same with any Python/Django version on any supported OS. You either have to change your url pattern so that it accepts spaces, or disallow spaces in `Tag.tag_name`, or use a `models.SlugField` that slugifies the tag name and use this slug for the url.